# Write $\sqrt{5}$ as sums of powers of $1 + \sqrt{2}$?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

The number $A = 1 + \sqrt{2}$ solve the equation $A^2 = 1 + 2 \sqrt{2} + 2 = 1+2A$.   We also have that $$0 < \dots < A^{-2} <  A^{-1} < 1 < A < A^2 < \dots $$ The powers are in increasing order.  Any real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is close to a sum of powers of $A$, $x \approx \sum a_i A^i$ with $a_i = 0, 1$ or $2$.

The $\beta$-expanson or the [$q$-expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Expansion.html) requires $0 \leq a_i \leq \lfloor 1+\sqrt{2}\rfloor=2$ in this case.
 There's also an article on [Golden ratio base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base), but that's $B = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $B^2 = B+1$.

Let's try $x = 3$.  We could have $x = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3$. That's not acceptable in our base expansion, since we are writing $x = 3 \times 1$.  So instead let's write $2 = A + \frac{1}{A}$.  Then we have a complete answer $3  = A^{-1} + 1 + A$.

What happens with $x= \sqrt{5}$?  I know it's between $1$ and $2$.  We have $2 < \sqrt{5} < 1 + (1+\sqrt{2})$.  Can we get ten decimal places?  Or even 100?

Comment: let me know if this question is ill-posed.  these are always drafts.

Comment: You should ask this on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Note that $A^{-1}=-1+\sqrt{2}$, thus all powers of $A$--both positive and negative--and therefore all base-$A$ numbers are expressible in the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$ with $p$ and $q$ integers.  Since $\sqrt{5}$ is not of that form, it will not have a terminating expansion; but, like other real numbers, it does have a unique nonterminating expansion, beginning $0.2010201001\ldots$

Comment: Also, you get about $\log_{10}(1+\sqrt{2})\approx 0.38$ decimal digits of precision for each additional base-$A$ digit, so to get 100 decimal places you need around 260 base-$A$ digits.